# Story about finding an alien fossil near dinosaur fossils

Tags: story-identification, aliens, dinosaurs

There's a story (I think it's Soviet SciFi), with an alien fossil found near a fossil of a dinosaur with laser-drilled holes in its skeleton, and the story revolves about finding the skull of one of the aliens hunting dinosaurs.

I read the book many years ago, but I can't recall the name of the story.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please take a look at our [guide on how to ask a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936), and [edit] your question with any additional details you remember (such as approximately how many years ago).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this (when was "many years ago")?  Did you read this in Russian or another language?  Was it in an anthology, a magazine, online...?

Comment: I think it was about 20 years ago, and I'm pretty sure I read it in spanish, maybe in an anthology.

Comment: An alternate explanation https://www.nature.com/articles/news.2007.372

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After DavidW asked about an anthology I started looking around, and I'm almost sure the short story is "[Stellar Ships](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?98789)" by Ivan Yefremov, and the book was [*Lo mejor de la ciencia ficción rusa*](https://tercerafundacion.net/biblioteca/ver/libro/24586) ("The Best of Russian Sci-fi").

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_Ships):

> "Stellar Ships" or "Star Ships" (Russian name "Zvezdnye Korabli", Russian: Звёздные корабли) is a short story by the Soviet writer and paleontologist Ivan Yefremov written in 1944 and first published in 1948 in the USSR.
>
> This story is about the discovery of an ancient dinosaur bone with a mysterious bullet hole (or "blaster hole") and an alien skull and his portrait nearby. This acts as a starting point and a cover story to the philosophical idea of plurality of the mind cradles in the Universe, similarity of planet evolution paths, and similarity of physiology and psychology. Yefremov states the final perspective for all civilisations is The Great Circle, which will unite them all.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The writing and publication of the story predate the first laser (1960), cited by the OP as the source of the holes...